# Prove that the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit is equivalent to this other definition

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I'm reading *Differential and Integral Calculus* by Piskunov, and found this another definition of limit (along with the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definiton):
[image: alternate definition of a limit]
The topic just ends by stating that it is easy to prove that the two definitions are equivalent. I've been thinking of it for some time but without any progress. It is clear intuitively, but how can I prove this mathematically?

Comment: i'm using the same book, think of his first definition like this: if you have the ordering $|x^{*} - a| < |x^{**} - a|$, then $x^{**}$ must come later than $x^{*}$, since that would mean $x^{**}$ is closer to $a$. then he says that if the distance from a of two different values of the variable $x$ is the same, then one point is at the right of $a$, while the smaller is on the left. he's basically making sure his intuitive definition works.

Comment: His definition makes no sense. He’s providing an ordering on the x and then stating something about the ordering of f(x). It seems like by this definition, $1+1/n$ has limit 1 since it’s always getting closer which makes no sense.